# Как вывести статистику за последние сутки

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе данных есть таблица `logs`, в которую записываем дату (в формате DATETIME: 2018-02-07 10:00 ) и значение - int.

Структура таблицы: id - auto_incrememt. date - datetime. value - int.

Запись в таблицу идет каждые 5 минут, и тогда мы имеем записи вида:

```
date: 2018-02-07 10:00 | value - 5
date: 2018-02-07 10:05 | value - 7
date: 2018-02-07 10:10 | value - 12
date: 2018-02-07 10:15 | value - 0
date: 2018-02-07 10:20 | value - 3
и так далее
```

Нужно вывести сумму значений value за последние сутки (24 часа). 
Как это сделать правильно?

Comment: Какая хоть база? `select sum(value) srom logs where date(date) = '2018-02-07'`

Comment: @ilyaplot база MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM logs WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: `date >= NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` Выбираете 24 часа завтра. Видимо - interval?

Comment: получаю массив только: `array (size=1) 'sum(value)' => null`

Comment: Ооуу, да ошибочка надо `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: а почему я получаю на выходе массив? `array (size=1) 'sum(value)' => null`

Comment: Это уже надо смотреть код. `SELECT` работает правильно, проверил

Answer (score 2):

Возможно поможет:

```
SELECT SUM(`value`) as `sum` FROM `logs`
WHERE `date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAYS)
```